# Реферальная система Telegram Bot + SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Испробовал множество структур хранения данных но никак не могу разобраться как это все реализовать в телеграм. 
Имеется таблица sqlite3

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id          INTEGER       NOT NULL ON CONFLICT REPLACE
                              PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    user_id     INT           NOT NULL
                              UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
    user_login  VARCHAR (200),
    user_name   TEXT,
    second_name TEXT,
    clock       DATE,
    parent_id   INTEGER, #Родитель
    refferer_id INTEGER #Наследник
);
```

Типы данных хранимых в таблице

```
1   111111111   @Login1 Вася    Сергеевич   1530548557  ksgytknvkl  0
2   222222222   @Login2 Иосиф   Сталин      1530548607  yvlwrjvuvy  ksgytknvkl
```

Мне необходима простая реферальная система без ответвлений просто вести подсчет сколько один пользователь пригласил людей и соответственно отоброжать это ему в сообщении

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покажу на примере `pyTelegramBotApi`.

Файл `main.py`:

```
from models import *
from telebot import TeleBot

bot = TeleBot('<token>')
ref_link = 'https://telegram.me/{}?start={}'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    splited = message.text.split()
    if not Users.user_exists(user_id):
        Users.create_user(user_id)
        if len(splited) == 2:
            Users.increase_ref_count(splited[1])
    bot.reply_to(message, text='hello')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ref'])
def get_my_ref(message):
    bot_name = bot.get_me().username
    bot.reply_to(message, text=ref_link.format(bot_name, message.chat.id))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ref_count'])
def get_my_refs(message):
    count = Users.get_ref_count(message.chat.id)
    bot.reply_to(message, text=f'Count: {count}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Файл `models.py`:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('users.db')


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class Users(BaseModel):
    user_id = IntegerField(unique=True)
    ref = IntegerField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls, user_id):
        return cls.get(user_id == user_id)

    @classmethod
    def get_ref_count(cls, user_id):
        return cls.get_user(user_id).ref

    @classmethod
    def increase_ref_count(cls, user_id):
        user = cls.get_user(user_id)
        user.ref += 1
        user.save()

    @classmethod
    def user_exists(cls, user_id):
        query = cls().select().where(cls.user_id == user_id)
        return query.exists()

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, user_id):
        user, created = cls.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
```

Не забываем создать таблицу:

```
db.create_tables([Users])
```

Comment: Спасибо это именно то что я искал все работает даже ничего не пришлось менять

Comment: @Stalin там не учитывается тот момент, если вместо `user_id` в параметр к `/start` будет передано что-то другое, например строка, тогда все слетит

Comment: как создать таблицу Users? Можно код?

Comment: да только есть проблемы в том что у всех почему что показывает одинаковое кол-во рефералов, а вообще от первого пользователя
мучаюсь долго не могу решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

Немного улучшенная версия от Pavel Durmanov:

main.py:

```
from models import *
from telebot import TeleBot

bot = TeleBot('TOKEN')
ref_link = 'https://telegram.me/{}?start={}'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    splited = message.text.split()
    if not Users.user_exists(user_id):
        Users.create_user(user_id)
        if len(splited) == 2:
            Users.increase_ref_count(splited[1])
    bot.reply_to(message, text='hello')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ref'])
def get_my_ref(message):
    bot_name = bot.get_me().username
    bot.reply_to(message, text=ref_link.format(bot_name, message.chat.id))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ref_count'])
def get_my_refs(message):
    count = Users.get_ref_count(message.chat.id)
    bot.reply_to(message, text=f'Count: {count}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

models.py:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('users.db')


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class Users(BaseModel):
    user_id = IntegerField(unique=True)
    ref = IntegerField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls, user_id):
        return cls.get(user_id == user_id)

    @classmethod
    def get_ref_count(cls, user_id):
        return cls.get(Users.user_id == user_id).ref

    @classmethod
    def increase_ref_count(cls, user_id):
        user = cls.get_user(user_id)
        user.ref += 1
        user.save()

    @classmethod
    def user_exists(cls, user_id):
        query = cls().select().where(cls.user_id == user_id)
        return query.exists()

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, user_id):
        user, created = cls.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)

#db.create_tables([Users]) #Создание таблицы
```

Исключена проблема что у всех одинаковое кол-во рефералов